# SectionList data variable change to something like items in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

How can i change the scheme for data to something like items or agents in our array that we providing to sectionList.
section list accepts array like this :
`const DATA = [ { title: 'Main dishes', data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'], }, { title: 'Sides', data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'], }, { title: 'Drinks', data: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer'], }, { title: 'Desserts', data: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'], }, ];`
**is it possible to change the data to agent**
`const DATA = [ { title: 'Main dishes', agent: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'], }, { title: 'Sides', agent: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'], }, { title: 'Drinks', agent: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer'], }, { title: 'Desserts', agent: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'], }, ];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing the whole section to the function and then got the item from section based on the index

```
const DATA = [{
    title: 'Main dishes',
    agent: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto'],
    data: ['Pizza', 'Burger', 'Risotto']
}, {
    title: 'Sides',
    agent: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'],
    data: ['French Fries', 'Onion Rings', 'Fried Shrimps'],
}, { title: 'Drinks', agent: ['Water', 'Coke', 'Beer'], }, {
    title: 'Desserts',
    agent: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'],
    data: ['Cheese Cake', 'Ice Cream'],
},];

const renderItem=({ section, item, index })=>{
return <RenderItemComponent data={section.agent[index]} key={index} />
}

<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
  renderItem={renderItem} 
  renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible, As **section list uses Flatlist component props in array of sections**.

See [Section Data Prop Document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#section)

One thing you can do is to **use the reduce function to change the agent key in your response to data** key.

**eg.**

```
DATA.reduce((prevVal, currVal) => {
    const arr = [...prevVal]
    const objData = [...currVal.agent]
    delete currVal.agent
    const res = [...arr, {
        ...currVal,
        data: objData
    }]
    return res
}, [])
```